# Populating ListView with multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: android

I am trying to populate ListView , as in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm
And it is working fine (see code below)

// Array of strings...
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now, instead of this mobileArray (one dimensional array), I want to use an ArrayList

I have already populated the arraylist named Students

But when I populate it as:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>(this, R.layout.activity_listview,Students);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and run I get a strange output

```
abc.mycom.com.collectionsample.Students@e3c94gh
abc.mycom.com.collectionsample.Students@erdgdhdf
abc.mycom.com.collectionsample.Students@eyfgbgfb
```

actually students has 3 rows... But no values such as e3c94gh

Please help me to do this with minimal code change - I mean -

My aim is just to replace mobileArray with Students (with minimal code change)

```
ArrayList population code is here:

 List<Student> Students = new ArrayList();


        Student student1 = new Student();

        student1.setStudentName("student 1");
        student1.setStudentNo("N0001");
        student1.setEmail("student1@student.com");
        student1.setYear(1991);

        Students.add(student1);


        Student student2 = new Student();

        student2.setStudentName("Student 2");
        student2.setStudentNo("N0002");
        student2.setEmail("student2@student.com");
        student2.setYear(1992);

        Students.add(student2);


        Student student3 = new Student();

        student3.setStudentName("Student 3");
        student3.setStudentNo("N0003");
        student3.setEmail("student3@student.com");
        student3.setYear(1993);

        Students.add(student3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
ArrayAdapter<Student> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Student>(this, R.layout.activity_listview,Students);
```

And where is your Students arrayList???

Comment: applied change ArrayAdapter<Student>.   No change at all.  I shall update with the ArrayList population steps also

Comment: Try to change "R.layout.activity_listview" ===>>> "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1"

Comment: If you want to show multiple information in a row of ListView, you must custom it. Here is where you need to start with: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/